# injection in nunit test

Tags: .net, unit-testing, code-injection

I have:

```
using Ninject;
public class ServiceManager : IServiceHelper
{

   [Inject]
    public IEntityRepository<User, UserCriteria> UserRepository
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

     public User GetUserById(object id)
    {
        User user = UserRepository.GetById(id);

        if (user != null && user.IsHolding.HasValue && user.IsHolding.Value)
            user.Companies = GetAllCompanies().ToList();
        return user;
    }
}
```

I wont write test on `GetUserById()`. I have to now what is it doing, which result it's method gives me.
note that UserCriteria not in my namespace (i cannot see it from my test) `UserRepository.GetById(id)` - makes request to database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need to do is supply a mock object for your UserRepository property so that you don't hit the database and can provide whatever results you like to verify your GetUserById method is working correctly.

For example, using NSubstitute you could do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetUserByIdDoesSomething()
{
    var userRepository = Substitute.For<IEntityRepository<User, UserCriteria>>();
    //Do something to ensure GetAllCompanies will return a value
    var user = new User();
    userRepository.GetById(Arg.Any<object>()).Returns(user);

    var serviceManager = new ServiceManager();
    serviceManager.UserRepository = userRepository;
    var result = serviceManager.GetUserById(1);
    Assert.AreEqual(user, result);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Companies.Count() > 0);
}
```